# Incorporating probability and random draw in my simulink model

Tags: block, matlab, simulink

Here are the basics - I've got a model with a computed distance between 2 objects. The likelihood that object A will detect object B is a probability dependent on distance (and its a cumulative lognormal curve).

I want to include a probability function based on that computed distance. So that at X meters, the probability of detection is 20%. At Y distance its 50% etc. At each step of the model, the distance will be different, so it needs to redo its random draw from the probability function and output whether or not object B was detected.

I was under the impression that the uncertain state block within the robust control toolbox was the direction to go, but so far I haven't been able to decipher the "help" information to learn how to use and apply it. (And as far as I can understand, it would be ideal b/c I can also run the model varying all the uncertain variables a certain number of times from the command line).

HELP PLEASE!!!